# Generic methodology for dealing with loading .dll files

Tags: .net, powershell

I'm looking to (potentially) use a .dll in a script to extend the script's functionality. But getting doco on what's in the .dll is difficult (I've seen blogs that suggest what I want might be possible). But then I got side tracked, and started to think how to do this generically?

How do you learn what's available to the PowerSheller in a .dll.

So I know I can load the .dll using `Add-Type`, and I think I can use `[appdomain]::CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()` (learnt of that just today) with a `| select ExportedTypes`, and I think from there I can do `[custom.type] | gm` to find the methods, but from there I get a little unstuck. How do I find the overloads for a given method?

Have I even got my initial steps correct? I notice the `location` property from the `[appdomain]` output doesn't match the .dll exactly. (The .dll might be in Program Files, but [appdomain] finds one in C:\windows\Microsoft.net\assembly - or is that just where it gets copied to?)

Comment: This is not uncommon. As long as it is discoverable using $env or .Net namespaces, where it physically resides, should not matter. Custome DLLs, et all is a different matter, and you have to fully qualify them

Answer (score 2):

Continuing from my comment...

Here are a few discovery options and then you just work from there. This from a 20K+ (regularly updated) file, which I personally use and provide to my teammates and my students in class deliveries.

```
<#
Get any .NET types and their static methods from PowerShell.
Enumerate all that are currently loaded into your AppDomain.
#>

([appdomain]::CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()) |
 Out-GridView

[AppDomain]::CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies() |
foreach { $PSItem.GetTypes() } |
foreach { $PSItem.GetMethods() } |
where { $PSItem.IsStatic } |
select DeclaringType, Name |
Out-GridView -PassThru -Title '
.NET types and their static methods'

<#
($Assembly_Infos = ([appdomain]::CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()) | 
Where {$PSItem.Modules.name.contains("presentationframework.dll")})
#>

($Assembly_Infos = ([appdomain]::CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()) | 
Where {$PSItem.Location -Match 'presentationframework.dll'})

$Assembly_Infos.GetModules().gettypes() | 
Where{$PSItem.isPublic -AND $PSItem.isClass} | 
select Name, BaseType | 
Out-GridView -Title '.Net Assembly Type information.'

# all the built-in .NET type accelerators in PowerShell:
[PSObject].Assembly.GetType('System.Management.Automation.TypeAccelerators')::
Get |
Out-GridView

# Using a type accelerator
[ADSI].FullName

# Finding the properties of a .NET class
[System.Environment].DeclaredProperties.Name
[ADSI].DeclaredProperties.Name


# Looping through static properties.
$obj = [environment]
$obj | get-member -Static -MemberType property |
foreach name |
foreach { "$PSitem = $($obj::$PSitem)" }

<# 
Instantiate the types using new-object and call instance methods.
You can use get-member on an instance to get the methods on a type.
#>

$Object = [psobject].Assembly.GetType('System.Management.Automation.TypeAccelerators')::get
$Object | Get-Member
$Object | Get-Member -Static
$Object.GetType()
$Object.GetEnumerator()


# Show Public methods
[System.Management.Automation.ModuleIntrinsics]::GetModulePath

# Show Private methods
[System.Management.Automation.ModuleIntrinsics] |
Get-Member -Static

# Using an addon module
Find-Module -Name ImpliedReflection |
Save-Module -Path "$env:USERPROFILE\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules -Force -Verbose"
Install-Module -Name ImpliedReflection
[System.Management.Automation.ModuleIntrinsics]
[System.Management.Automation.ModuleIntrinsics] |
Get-Member -Static

# Query Powershell Data Types
[AppDomain]::CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies() |
Foreach-Object { $PSItem.GetExportedTypes() }

# Or

[psobject].Assembly.GetType(“System.Management.Automation.TypeAccelerators”)::get

# Or

[psobject].Assembly.GetType("System.Management.Automation.TypeAccelerators")::
Get.GetEnumerator() | 
Sort-Object -Property Key
```

Comment: This is some very cool stuff. However, how do I get overload definitions?